# jquery string breaks in single quote

Tags: jquery

```
var workername = 'test test';
```

there is a space in string so it is breaks in the makeapp variable.

```
$.each(data.workerids,function(j)
            {
                var classname = '';
                var makeapp = '';
                if(typeof(data.workerTimes[data.workerids[j]]) != "undefined" && $.inArray(data.shopTimeArray[i],data.workerTimes[data.workerids[j]]) !== -1 )
                {
                    classname = 'orange';
                    var workername = data.workernames[j]; //this is a json string.
                    var makeapp = 'onclick=make_app("'+data.today+'","'+data.shopTimeArray[i].slice(0,-3)+'","'+workername+'")'; //at here it is not working properly.
                }
                else
                {
                    classname = 'grey';
                }
                html += '<td class="'+classname+'" '+makeapp+'></td>';  
            });
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A9xP.jpg)

Comment: Create your elements with `createElement` and add the events with `addEventListener`, and everything becomes easier. Or, since you've tagged this with jQuery, use jQuery !

Comment: @adeneo how? can you give me any example..

Comment: You'd write it more like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/cqLa928n/2/

Comment: Sorry i run that code but didn't get success.. @adeneo